# Should I have to pay for Garage Band if I bought my iMac with OS X 10.8?

Tags: imac, macos, garageband

I've recently started a project that's going to entail using GarageBand. I'd heard it was free, and I searched it in Spotlight. Just to clarify, I am currently running El Capitan. Lo and behold, it did not appear in Spotlight, despite having a reference to the GarageBand app in the App Store. I clicked the App Store link, and it took me to the GarageBand app page where I observed, my confusion growing by the minute, that its price was actually $4.99. I googled it and arrived at an apple site saying that GarageBand is free to all users that have used 10.10. I bought my iMac with OS X Mountain Lion and since then have updated to El Capitan. While I haven't downloaded GarageBand ever I'm pretty sure, I should still have access, no? Every other iApp is there: iPhoto, iMovie, Keynote, Pages and Numbers, so why not GarageBand? I've still got the installation apps for Mavericks and Yosemite, and I had a friend recommend I partition my drive and install Mavericks and bring GarageBand over, but I've got no clue how to do that and I've had bad experiences with downgrading OS, so I'd definitely need guidance if that's the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Garageband used to be free. There was also a $4.99 in-app purchase to get extras. However, Apple changed it to make Garageband $4.99 and not charge for the extras.

Comment: I'm aware of that, however I "owned" Garageband when it was free, and supposedly it came with the OS and was waiting for me to download it. Therefore, I should own Garageband regardless of whether or not I update, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Around May 2017 - the iLife apps are free to download for iOS and Mac. See this thread for details.

- [How do I get iWork / iMovie / Garage Band free of charge?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/280764/how-do-i-get-iwork-imovie-garage-band-free-of-charge)